# CSS icons, can I translate one class to another

Tags: css, icons

I am building an app in Django and I have added some classes to my divs to indicate cetrain states - pass, fail, waiting.

```
<div class="pass data-sent">content</div>
```

These class names were chosen, as they represent a particular state I wish to indicate in the application.

Now I have come across a set of icons that I would like to use -

http://ionicons.com/

These icons seem to be added by adding the class to the div, for example

```
<li class="icon-alert-circled"></li>
```

Is there a way I can "translate" my 'fail' class to the 'icon-alert-class'  to display this icon?

(The github page has build instructions using Sass - could I rename the icons / classnames that way?)

Comment: Do you mean have the icon applied to the `fail` class instead of `icon-alert-circled`?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't "import" one rule into another (unless you paste all the ionicons styles into your own so that SASS parses them), but you can apply the same styles as the rule. You can check what the rule uses, but basically you just need the character, the font and the size:

```
.fail {
  font-family: Ionicons;
  font-size: 32px;
}
.fail:before {
  content: ""
}
```